# Haskell: Lambdabot installation unable to complete

Tags: haskell, cabal-install, lambdabot

I'm trying to install lambdabot.  The installation keeps terminating at step 74/100 and gives me the error below.

Any suggestions on how to resolve?  Has anyone experienced a similar issue?

If relevant, I'm attempting to install with following command (so as to point it toward the pcre files which it was complaining about earlier): `sudo cabal install "--extra-include-dirs=/usr/local/lib/")`.

```
src/Lambdabot/Plugin/Pointful.hs:57:12:
    Constructor `PatBind' should have 4 arguments, but has been given 5
    In the pattern:
      PatBind locat
              (PVar fname)
              Nothing
              (UnGuardedRhs (Lambda _ pats rhs))
              (BDecls [])
    In an equation for `optimizeD':
        optimizeD
          (PatBind locat
                   (PVar fname)
                   Nothing
                   (UnGuardedRhs (Lambda _ pats rhs))
                   (BDecls []))
          = FunBind
              [Match locat fname pats Nothing (UnGuardedRhs rhs) (BDecls [])]

src/Lambdabot/Plugin/Pointful.hs:177:22:
    Constructor `PatBind' should have 4 arguments, but has been given 5
    In the pattern:
      PatBind _ (PVar fname) _ (UnGuardedRhs body) (BDecls [])
    In an equation for `declToTuple':
        declToTuple
          (PatBind _ (PVar fname) _ (UnGuardedRhs body) (BDecls []))
          = (UnQual fname, Paren body)
    In an equation for `combinators':
        combinators
          = M.fromList $ map declToTuple defs
          where
              defs
                = case parseModule combinatorModule of {
                    ParseOk (Hs.Module _ _ _ _ _ _ d) -> d
                    f@(ParseFailed _ _) -> error ("Combinator loading: " ++ show f) }
              declToTuple
                (PatBind _ (PVar fname) _ (UnGuardedRhs body) (BDecls []))
                = (UnQual fname, Paren body)
              declToTuple _
                = error "Pointful Plugin error: can't convert declaration to tuple"
Failed to install lambdabot-4.3.0.1
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
lambdabot-4.3.0.1 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
dchaudh@dchaudhUbuntu:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

You should update your `haskell-src-exts` to the latest version by running

```
cabal update
cabal install haskell-src-exts
```